# flutter different ways to get files in flutter with extensions like mp3,pd,zip

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I used a function to get files but the app get slow I need different ways to get files in a flutter. adding a loop to get files from device storage etc.

**function to get files**

```
 void getFiles() async {
if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
  // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
}
//asyn function to get list of files
List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
var root = storageInfo[0]
    .rootDir; //storageInfo[1] for SD card, geting the root directory
var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); //
files = await fm.filesTree(
    excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/ssssssssssss"],
    extensions: ["mp3"] //optional, to filter files, list only pdf files
);

setState(() {}); //update the UI
```

}

Comment: Reading the entire sdcard is always going to be slow. You can cache the result for future once read. You can profile refresh functionality to sync the temporary data on subsequent launch of the app.

Comment: shared my code i used this function and call it inside initState but before moving to this screen that contain list of files on tap navigation get slow cuz in next screen this function is called in initState

Comment: can you plz edit im trying from 3 days

Comment: how do you call this method? from initState? I believe you don't await for it in initState method.

Comment: i think app get stuck during navigate to page 2 some times cuz init state call again and again mean gettng files again when move to other screen and come back .Is there a method that calls once in every screen?

Comment: void initState() {
   

     getFiles();

Comment: why don't you try walk method of FileManager? It might be more optimized.